# Shell script – New script not inheriting values from parent script after `exec`

Tags: shell-script, shell, process, exec

I wrote a shell script named `testmain.sh`:

```
username="ravi"
echo "The main ProcessId: "
echo $$
exec ./process.sh
```

With `process.sh` being:

```
echo "In subprocess the process ID is:"
echo $$
echo $username
```

I am executing it with `./testmain.sh`.

I was expecting that `$username` in `process.sh` should be printed as "ravi", as the main process (`testmain.sh`) and the sub-process (`process.sh`) share the same process ID. However, I see nothing is printed for the username in `process.sh`.

Why is the shell behaving like this? 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The term ‘‘sub-process’’ is not really appropriate, since you are talking about the same process throughout.

Answer (score 1):

Variables must be exported if they're to be passed on to the environment of external commands, even for `exec`d commands. Otherwise you'll have to `source` the script.

So either:

```
export username="ravi"
echo "The main ProcessId: "
echo $$
exec ./process.sh
```

Or:

```
username="ravi"
echo "The main ProcessId: "
echo $$
. ./process.sh  # source the script
```

This is because, while `exec` inherits environment variables (just like when you normally run a command), an unexported variable is not added to the environment.

Comment: What is the difference between export vs sourcing. Getting a bit of "hard to understand" answers while googling.

Comment: @sai When you export a variable, it's added to the environment of any commands you run. When you source a script, that script is run in the current shell, so every variable (exported or not), function, trap, etc. from the current shell is available to the script and everything the script does affects the shell (unlike when you execute a script, it cannot effect the shell from which you started it). It's as if you ran the commands in the script in the shell directly (with some minor exceptions).

Comment: okay..got it.  So, "sourcing" means, you are importing a class (as in java). So you get all the parent class features into the child class and export is means, you are only adding some attributes to environment variables. So, I believe mostly we will use only export. If we require any methods (or) multiple variables/methods etc of another script, we go  for "sourcing".

Comment: @sai I don't know much about Java, but your last sentence seems right to me: sourcing is needed for including functions from another script. Basically the question is: when script A runs script B, do you want B to affect A or for everything in A to be available to B ? Then B should be sourced.